# Assign pointer to a function the address of a pointer to function object

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers, functor

Is it possible in C++?
For example I have a pointer to a function that takes no parameters and its return type is void:

```
void (*f)();
```

and and a function object:

```
class A
{
public:
    void operator()() { cout << "functor\n"; }
};
```

Is it possible to assign to `f` the address of an `A` object? And when I call `f()` to call the `A` functor?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    void operator()() { cout << "functorA\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    A ob;
    ob();
    void (*f)();
    f = &ob;
    f();       // Call ob();
    return 0;
}
```

I get `C:\Users\iuliuh\QtTests\functor_test\main.cpp:15: error: C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'A *' to 'void (__cdecl *)(void)'
There is no context in which this conversion is possible`

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Can't you just use `std::function<void()>`?

Comment: Is there any way to do it with the old standard, the one before c++11?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it in the way you've specified, because:

1. operator() must be a nonstatic function (standards requirement)
2. a pointer to a non-static function must have an implicit parameter - the pointer to the class instance
3. your call to f() does not give any indication on which instance of the object A your function is called

Using C++11 and std::function, as Stephane Rolland pointed out, may do the trick - you'll be specifying the pointer to the object in the binding:

```
std::function<void(void)> f = std::bind(&A::operator(), &ob);
```

(See [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582546/using-generic-stdfunction-objects-with-member-functions-in-one-class) on using std::function on member functions)

Answer (score 3):

If you use C++11, could use [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

```
#include <functional>

std::function<void()> f;

int main()
{
    A ob;
    ob();

    f = ob;    // f refers to ob
    f();       // Call ob();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's kind of possible using a C++1/C++0x feature, but to achieve this you should use the **std::function** which can address to the two types, functions and object functions.

```
#include <functional>

 class A
{
public:
    void operator()() { }
};

int main()
{
    std::function<void(void)> aFunction;
    A ob;

    aFunction = ob;

// or as another user said
// aFunction = std::bind(&A:operator(), &ob);

    aFunction();

    void (*f)();

    aFunction = f;

    aFunction();

    return 0;
}
```

and if you're stuck with C++03, you could play with `std::mem_fun` and `std::ptr_fun`

Answer (score 1):

How about some workaround like this:

Basically you want to have a common way of calling member functions and functions. Then maybe you could create a wrapper that would represent a generic pointer to either a function or member function. Let's say you have `Base` class and you want to be able to invoke `operator()` of all derived classes. Then you also have a `function()` that you want to invoke as well:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void operator()() = 0;
};

class A : public Base
{
public:
    void operator()(){ std::cout << "A()" << std::endl; }
};

void function()
{
    std::cout << "function" << std::endl; 
}
```

If you create an wrapper that allows you to construct your custom pointer (`MyFncPtr`):

```
typedef void (Base::*BaseFncPtr)();
typedef void (*FncPtr)();

class MyFncPtr
{
public:
    MyFncPtr(FncPtr f) : fnc(f), baseObj(NULL), baseFnc(NULL) { }
    MyFncPtr(BaseFncPtr fPtr, Base* objPtr) : baseFnc(fPtr), baseObj(objPtr), fnc(NULL)  { }
    void invoke()
    {
        if (baseObj && baseFnc)
            (baseObj->*baseFnc)();
        else if (fnc)
            fnc();
    }

private:
    BaseFncPtr baseFnc;
    Base* baseObj;
    FncPtr fnc;
};
```

you could achieve it like this:

```
A a;
MyFncPtr myPtr(&Base::operator(), &a);
myPtr.invoke();
MyFncPtr myPtr2(function);
myPtr2.invoke();
```

outputs:

```
A()
function
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Just note that it's rather concept that final solution. You should consider problem with dangling pointers when you still keep the `MyPtr` object once the original `baseObj` is destructed, etc. Smart pointers could be used so that it becomes more proper solution :)

Comment: +1 for workaround which works without the new C++11 features. Thank you!

Comment: @JohnSmith: You're welcome :) Yeah, I wanted to point out that there are other solutions than those relying on C++0x/C++11 ;)