# How to access the member functions of a Functor using std::function in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, functor

I have a class in C++ that is also a functor, as well as contains another member function. The return values of the functions depend on both x and alpha.

```
class A {
    A(double x) : x(x) { }
    /* snip */
    double operator() (double x);
    double derivative(double x);
    double alpha = 1.0;
}
```

I want to access both of these and store them in function objects in another class
like this:

```
class B {
    /* snip */
    function<double(double)> f;
    function<double(double)> d;
}
```

I want to initialize both f and d in B's constructor. I figured that the following can initialize f

```
this->f = A(1.0);
```

OR

```
A a(1.0);
this->f = a;
```

My question is: How can I achieve the same initialisation for d?
I am using g++ 4.8.1 (C++11 syntax)

Comment: Both of these "initializations" aren't, they're assignments. To initialize, you just want something like `: f(1.0)` in the constructor initializer list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to bind the member function to an instance of A:

```
d = std::bind(&A::derivative, &a, std::placeholders::_1);
```

where `a` is an instance of `A`. This is because member functions have an implicit first parameter for `this`.

Comment: That works great :) :) !! Though I'll still be on the look for a cleaner solution.

Comment: @AbhraBasak you will always need to pass an instance to a non-static member function, otherwise it cannot access any other non-static members. But if you do not need any of these, you can make `A::derivative` a static member function. That won't have an implicit 1st parameter.

Comment: You are right. I just found a similar thread here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582546/using-generic-stdfunction-objects-with-member-functions-in-one-class