# How can I expand this C++11 event system to handle multiple arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11, event-handling, stl

I've written a simple subscriber event system taking advantage of `std::function`. It works great! (and I can do some big enhancements later with thread-pooling for expensive callbacks)

The next step to improve this is to handle events/callbacks with more than one parameter.

Other than forcing `struct`s/`class`es or using `std::tuple`s in the callback arguments (I want to keep the functions clean or use existing simple funcs).  Is there a good way to do this, and have multiple template parameters all with the same code?

```
#pragma once

#include <mutex>
#include <vector>


template<typename PARAM>
class SoyEvent
{
public:
    typedef std::function<void(PARAM&)> FUNCTION;

public:
    //  helper for member functions
    template<class CLASS>
    void            AddListener(CLASS& This,void(CLASS::*Member)(PARAM&))
    {
        //  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7582576
        auto bound = std::bind( Member, &This, std::placeholders::_1  );
        AddListener( bound );
    }
    template<class CLASS>
    void            RemoveListener(CLASS& This,FUNCTION Member)
    {
        RemoveListener( std::bind( &Member, &This ) );
    }

    //  add static or lambda
    void            AddListener(FUNCTION Function)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mListenerLock);
        mListeners.push_back(Function);
    }
    void            RemoveListener(FUNCTION Function)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mListenerLock);
        mListeners.erase(Function);
    }

    void            OnTriggered(PARAM& Param)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mListenerLock);

        //  todo: execute on seperate threads with a scheduler which can just execute std::functions
        for ( auto it=mListeners.begin();   it!=mListeners.end();   it++ )
        {
            auto& Function = *it;
            Function( Param );
        }
    }

private:
    std::mutex      mListenerLock;
    std::vector<FUNCTION>   mListeners;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use variadic templates, i.e. change your class definition from:

```
template <typename PARAM>
class SoyEvent {
     // Implementation
};
```

To something like:

```
template <typename... PARAMS>
class SoyEvent {
     // Implementation
};
```

And then change your `FUNCTION` typedef to:

```
typedef std::function<void(PARAMS&...)> FUNCTION;
```

And in general change all instances of `PARAM&` to `PARAMS&...`.

Comment: Though a great comment. There is not enough detail here for an inexperienced programmer to actually implement your idea. Also this site is for reviewing existing code not for designing enhancements. Because of the low number of reviewers on this site we would be doing the OP a disservice by not pointing at a more trafficked site were more people could potentially answer the question.