# C++ User-defined type conversion failure

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
template<typename T>
class Pack
{
private:
    std::function<T()> _Func = nullptr;
public:
    Pack()
    {
    }
    Pack(std::function<T()> func)
        : _Func(func)
    {
    }
    ~Pack()
    {
    }

    operator T()
    {
        return _Func();
    }
};
```

What I use is `operator T`, I want to call `_Func` implicitly but I cannot even do it explicitly. It seems right but actually error C2440 @MSVC. I use it in two ways:

1. static member of class (succeeded);
2. member of class (failed)

(I don't know whether it matters or not)

I'm really wondering why it performs in two ways, and more importantly, how I can put it into my class as a non-static member and successfully call the `operator T`.

Comment: You need to bind a non-static function to an object: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582546/using-generic-stdfunction-objects-with-member-functions-in-one-class) helps.

Comment: @namezero param is a lambda expression captures all by references in class. The same solution?

Comment: @namezero What's the question? your example works fine.

Comment: @AmiTavory If i put it into a class as an dynamic member, the `operator T` won't be automatically called if I write like this: int i = ClassInstance.IntPack;

Comment: It actually does just that in g++. If it doesn't do it in Visual, I suggest you add this to the tag of your question.

Comment: @AmiTavory That's strange.

Comment: Why's that strange. Compilers, especially VC++, don't always do things right. I strongly suggest you add this to your question tag, as it's currently misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Member of the class:

```
struct test
{
    test()
    {
        p_ = Pack<int>(std::bind(&test::foo, *this));
    }

    int foo()
    {
        std::cout << "test::foo" << std::endl;
        return 5;
    }

    Pack<int> p_;
};

int main()
{
    test t;
    int x = t.p_;

    return 0;
}
```

This works fine on VS 2013 EE.

Comment: I mean, the Pack is in a class and i want to use it in main() through the instance of the class

Comment: @PENGUINLIONG what is your compiler version? This code works even on VS2010 if I remove _Func initialization within the class.

Comment: My suggestion will be to try Pack class with my code in a new empty project and if that is not working then install updates - I compiled the code using VS2013 update 4.