# How to store type information, gathered from a constructor, at the class level to use in casting

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I am trying to write a class that I can store and use type information in without the need for a template parameter.

I want to write something like this:

```
class Example
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    Example(T* ptr)
        : ptr(ptr)
    {
        // typedef T EnclosedType; I want this be a avaialable at the class level.
    }

    void operator()()
    {
        if(ptr == NULL)
            return;

        (*(EnclosedType*)ptr)(); // so i can cast the pointer and call the () operator if the class has one.
    }

private:
    void* ptr;
}
```

I am not asking how to write an is_functor() class.

I want to know how to get type information in a constructor and store it at the class level. If that is impossible, a different solution to this would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not T* ptr; ? As for the question to avoid specifying template parameter you need to provide default one.

Comment: I just wanted to ask the same question :)

Comment: This is called *type erasure*. You'll probably find more about this topic when searching for that term. You could also look up some implementation of `std::function` or `boost::function`, or watch Sean Parent's talkS at GoingNative 2013.

Comment: You could use  a `boost::any` as the member

Comment: I strongly recommend you look up the implementation of ``boost::any`` and read through it in some detail (it's not tiny, but it's not very long either). It's relatively free of really annoying details, and quite clever. Once you fully "get" ``boost::any``, you will really take a significant step in understanding types and type erasure in C++. (note that ``std::function`` does similar things, but is way more complicated in practice... so I recommend starting with ``any``).

Comment: The syntax to call `operator()` would be `(*(EnclosedType *)ptr)();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I consider this as a good and valid question, however, there is no general solution beside using a template parameter at the class level. What you tried to achieve in your question -- using a `typedef` inside a function and then access this in the whole class -- is not possible.

**Type erasure**

Only if you impose certain restrictions onto your constructor parameters, there are some alternatives. In this respect, here is an example of *type erasure* where the `operator()` of some given object is stored inside a `std::function<void()>` variable.

```
struct A
{
    template<typename T>
    A(T const& t) : f (std::bind(&T::operator(), t)) {}

    void operator()() const
    {
        f();
    }

    std::function<void()> f;
};

struct B
{
    void operator()() const
    {
        std::cout<<"hello"<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A(B{}).operator()();  //prints "hello"
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6969a62e8a63d131)

Note, however, the assumptions underlying this approach: one assumes that all passed objects have an operator of a given signature (here `void operator()`) which is stored inside a `std::function<void()>` (with respect to storing the member-function, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582546/using-generic-stdfunction-objects-with-member-functions-in-one-class)).

**Inheritance**

In a sense, type erasure is thus like "inheriting without a base class" -- one could instead use a common base class for all constructor parameter classes with a virtual bracket operator, and then pass a base class pointer to your constructor.

```
struct A_parameter_base
{
    void operator()() const = 0;
};

struct B : public A_parameter_base
{
    void operator()() const { std::cout<<"hello"<<std::endl; }           
};

struct A
{
    A(std::shared_ptr<A_parameter_base> _p) : p(_p) {}

    void operator()()
    {
        p->operator();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<A_parameter_base> p;
}
```

That is similar to the code in your question, only that it does not use a `void`-pointer but a pointer to a specific base class.

Both approaches, type erasure and inheritance, are similar in their applications, but type erasure might be more convenient as one gets rid of a common base class. However, the inheritance approach has the further advantage that you can restore the original object via multiple dispatch

This also shows the limitations of both approaches. If your operator would not be `void` but instead would return some unknown varying type, you cannot use the above approach but have to use templates. The inheritance parallel is: you cannot have a virtual function template.

Comment: You can restore the original object from a `std::function` if you know the exact stored type.  Second, why are you using `bind`?  `std::ref` seems much cleaner, and doesn't rely on the type being a class, nor having a non-overloaded `()`.

Answer (score 1):

The practical answer is to store either a copy of your class, or a `std::ref` wrapped pseudo-reference to your class, in a `std::function<void()>`.

`std::function` type erases things it stores down to 3 concepts: copy, destroy and invoke with a fixed signature.  (also, cast-back-to-original-type and typeid, more obscurely)

What it does is it remembers, at construction, how to do these operations to the passed in type, and stores a copy in a way it can perform those operations on it, then forgets everything else about the type.

You cannot remember everything about a type this way.  But almost any operation with a fixed signature, or which can be intermediaried via a fixed signature operation, can be type erased down to.

The first typical way to do this are to create a private pure interface with those operations, then create a template implementation (templated on the type passed to the ctor) that implements each operation for that particular type.  The class that does the type erasure then stores a (smart) pointer to the private interface, and forwards its public operations to it.

A second typical way is to store a `void*`, or a buffer of char, and a set of pointers to functions that implement the operations.  The pointers to functions can be either stored locally in the type erasing class, or stored in a helper struct that is created statically for each type erased, and a pointer to the helper struct is stored in the type erasing class.  The first way to store the function pointers is like C-style object properties: the second is like a manual vtable.

In any case, the function pointers usually take one (or more) `void*` and know how to cast them back to the right type.  They are created in the ctor that knows the type, either as instances of a `template` function, or as local stateless lambdas, or the same indirectly.

You could even do a hybrid of the two: static pimpl instance pointers taking a `void*` or whatever.

Often using `std::function` is enough, manually writing type erasure is hard to get right compared to using `std::function`.

Comment: @noob sure, which is covered by the 2nd form of type erasure, where you use a `void*` and a function pointer (or more).  For a particularly fast `()`, "fastest possible delegates" is a google-able hack of an implementation.  Less hacky you can write a move-only task object with a `unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)>` smart ptr and a invoke function pointer of type `void(*)(void*)` with no virtual method calls, using the 2nd technique above.

Comment: Thanks! although I can't tell what you mean without any example code, googling "fastest possible delegates" led me [hear](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/136799/Lightweight-Generic-C-Callbacks-or-Yet-Another-Del) which gave me the answer. However, since that question has already been asked, I will leave the title as is and choose an answer above. I will 1+ you though for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Another version to the first two answers we have here - that's closer to your current code:

```
class A{
public:
  virtual void operator()=0;
};

template<class T>
class B: public A{
public:
  B(T*t):ptr(t){}
  virtual void operator(){(*ptr)();}
  T*ptr;
};

class Example
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    Example(T* ptr)
    : a(new B<T>(ptr))
    {
        // typedef T EnclosedType; I want this be a avaialable at the class level.
    }

    void operator()()
    {
        if(!a)
            return;

        (*a)();
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<A> a;
}
```