# Refactor multiple repeated functions differing only at the innermost scope

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to find a refactoring solution to the following scenario. I have many duplicated functions, each doing exactly the same thing except calling a different member function on a class instance available only at the inner-most scope.

```
struct MyObject
{
    void Function1() {};
    void Function2() {};
    void Function3() {};
    void Function4() {};
};

std::vector<MyObject *> objects;

void CommandHandler1()
    {
    if (true) // lots of preconditions
        {
        size_t id = 0;
        if (true) // lots of lookup code for id
            {
            MyObject *myObject = objects.at(id);
            myObject->Function1();
            }
        // refresh code
        }
    // cleanup code
    }

// another CommandHandler2, CommandHandler3, CommandHandler4, etc. doing the same thing but for a different member function.
```

I'd like to avoid this duplication of multiple CommandHandlerx because they're so very similar. What I've tried is to pass a std::function to work on any instance, because I can't bind to a specific instance. [An answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582546/using-generic-stdfunction-objects-with-member-functions-in-one-class) implies that the following mini-program should compile.

```
#include <functional>

void CommandHandler(std::function<void(MyObject *)> func)
{
    if (true) // lots of preconditions
        {
        size_t id = 0; 
        if (true) // lots of lookup code for id
            {
            MyObject *myObject = objects.at(id);
            func(myObject);
            }
        }
    // cleanup code
}

void MenuHandler(int chosen)
    {
    switch (chosen)
        {
        case 0: CommandHandler( &MyObject::Function1); break;
        case 1: CommandHandler( &MyObject::Function2); break;
        case 2: CommandHandler( &MyObject::Function3); break;
        case 3: CommandHandler( &MyObject::Function4); break;
        }
    }

int main()
{
    MyObject *obj1 = new MyObject;
    MyObject *obj2 = new MyObject;
    objects.push_back(obj1);
    objects.push_back(obj2);

    MenuHandler(1);

    delete obj1; delete obj2;
    return 0;
}
```

This unfortunately doesn't build. I presume because I'm not binding against a specific `this` pointer:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\include\functional(506): error C2664: 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,MyObject *>::_Set(std::_Func_base<_Ret,MyObject
>   *> *)' : cannot convert argument 1 from '_Myimpl *' to 'std::_Func_base<_Ret,MyObject *> *'

My question is either (1) am I doing something wrong with the above std::function attempt, or (2) is there any other pattern for refactoring this scenario?

Comment: Your code should work. Probably MSVC bug (I know that they completely rewrote `<functional>` for VS2015, and heard that their original version had some difficulties with member pointers). Have you tried passing a pointer-to-member-function directly? (Make the parameter `void (MyObject::* func)()`, and call as `(myObject->*func)()`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code [works with GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f89e270b62b5bcd0), so it can very well be a peculiarity of MSVC's implementation of `std::function`. I'll offer some workarounds.

If the functions 1–4 really all follow the same signature, you don't need `std::function` at all and a plain old pointer to member function will do:

```
void CommandHandler(void (MyObject::*func)())
{
    if (true) // lots of preconditions
        {
        size_t id = 0; 
        if (true) // lots of lookup code for id
            {
            MyObject *myObject = objects.at(id);
            (myObject->*func)();
            }
        }
    // cleanup code
}
```

If you do need an opaque callable (e.g. because you're binding some parameters), you should be able to use `std::mem_fn` to obtain a suitable initialiser for `std::function`:

```
void MenuHandler(int chosen)
    {
    switch (chosen)
        {
        case 0: CommandHandler( std::mem_fn(&MyObject::Function1)); break;
        case 1: CommandHandler( std::mem_fn(&MyObject::Function2)); break;
        case 2: CommandHandler( std::mem_fn(&MyObject::Function3)); break;
        case 3: CommandHandler( std::mem_fn(&MyObject::Function4)); break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about `std::mem_fn`. Is it quite the same thing as `std::bind`, just without the possibility to also bind parameters?

Comment: @JBL Somewhat, but not quite. [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) can be used with data members as well.

Comment: Thanks for the alternatives.