# Adding std::function to a vector c++

Tags: function, c++11, pointers, vector

I have a vector containing function pointers

```
typedef bool (*fPtr)();
vector<fPtr> AlgoDB;
```

The functions that I push into the vectors are defined as below

```
bool SAlgos1::Algo1() {
    cout << "Executing Algo1" << endl;
    return true;
}
```

The below statement is used to add the functions / pointers to the vector

```
this->AlgoDB.push_back((fPtr) &this->Algo1);
```

This being the traditional C styled function pointer usage, I am trying to use the `std::function`, where the vector and the functions are modified now as below

```
typedef function<bool()> ffptr;
vector <ffptr> fAlgoDB;

function<bool()> SAlgos1::fAlgo1(){

    cout << "Executing FAlgo1";
    return true;
}
```

But now whenever I use the statement like this

`this->fAlgoDB.push_back(fAlgo1);` or `this->fAlgoDB.push_back(&fAlgo1);`
(typecasting doesn't help too - `this->fAlgoDB.push_back((ffptr) this->fAlgo1);`)

I get an error stating

`error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]` and

`error: could not convert 'true' from 'bool' to 'std::function<bool()>'` (even though I dont really call the function) for every alternate compilation.

How can I store the functions or function pointers in the vector? What is the compiler trying to convey?

Comment: You are *returning* an `std::function` from `fAlgo1` where you should return a `bool`. Also, your original code shouldn't even work with member functions because you have to state the type of the class in your function pointer typedef!

Comment: The original function works without the class type, its a compiler warning though!

Comment: You are invoking undefined behaviour if you define a function pointer to point to a global function, but instead use it to store a member function and then invoke it. Your `(fPtr)` cast simply hides the fact that you're casting incompatible things. Better to not use C style casts!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two problems in your example.

1. You changed the return type of your function from `bool` to `function<bool>`. Just leave it as `bool`, since that is the return type you want.
2. The the type of *pointer-to-member-function* is different from *pointer-to-function* (see https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types). This is due to the fact that a member function always passes the `this` pointer as an argument. You need to *bind* that argument (using `std::bind`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7582576/6095394).

The following example compiles fine.

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class SAlgos1
{
    typedef function<bool()> ffptr;

    bool fAlgo1()
    {
        cout << "Executing FAlgo1";
        return true;
    }

    void fillAlgoDB()
    {
        fAlgoDB.push_back(bind(&SAlgos1::fAlgo1, this));
    }

    vector<ffptr> fAlgoDB;
};
```

Comment: I would use lambda instead of `bind`. `bind` was a necessity when we didn't have lambdas. Now it's just a monster sitting in a corner. Since c++14 it became completely obsolete.

Comment: @bolov: Only since C++14, though. The question is tagged [tag:c++11] and, in C++11, the lack of generic lambdas makes `std::bind` preferable in several scenarios. Mind you, this isn't one of them. I guess that's all the same as what you said.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit exactly

Answer (score 1):

You are returning an `std::function` from `fAlgo1` where you should return a `bool`. Also, your original code shouldn't even work with member functions because you have to state the type of the class in your function pointer typedef!

The syntax is explained [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members). You could use

```
typedef bool (SAlgos1::*fPtr)();
```

to fix the function pointer.

Right now, you are invoking undefined behaviour because you declare a function pointer to point to a global function, but instead use it to store a member function and then invoke it. Your `(fPtr)` cast simply hides the fact that you're casting incompatible things. Better to not use C style casts!

Comment: This I understood, there is a mistake with the return parameter, as I do not know the syntax to define a member function which is actually std::function. thank you for that, but how do I define and push the std::function (member function) in the vector?

Comment: Use `this->AlgoDB.push_back(std::bind(&SAlgos1::fAlgo1, this));`