# Passing functions as arguments not working inside a class

Tags: c++, function, pointers

Creating a Foo object passing func to constructor works just fine in this example:

```
int func(int a) { return a; }

struct Foo {
  Foo( int (*func_ptr)(int) ) {};
};

Foo bar(func);
```

However attempting to create a Foo object inside another class does not:

```
class ThisIsCrap {
  Foo doesntWork(func);
};
```

How can I create a Foo object inside a class like I can outside a class? On the bit that doesn't compile, the error is: "cannot resolve type 'func'"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is fairly obvious once you realize that `MoreCrap::noFun` is *not a function*. It is a *member* function. Unlike a function, it cannot be called: `MoreCrap::noFun(10)` makes no sense. Member functions are different constructions that require a more complex set of data to be used, namely an object instance and arguments.

Comment: Okay, I can see that, but what about ThisIsCrap::doesntWork ?

Comment: That one doesn't even make syntactic sense. That's like `void f(10, int);`.

Comment: You can bind `this` to the member function and use it as a `std::function`, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7582576/104774)

Comment: You cannot initialize class members inline with round parentheses. Your example is a far too contrived way to demonstrate that; you should have a *much* simpler example, like `struct X { int a(5); };`.

Comment: May I edit your question to be more to the point?

Comment: Cannot initialize members inline..  #facepalm

Comment: You actually [can](http://ideone.com/eOOEv1).

Comment: @BryanFallin: ... *with round parentheses*. There are other ways in which you can do it.

Comment: @Kerrek, Please, I would love to know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide an initializer for non-static class data members with a *default member initializer* (DMI):

```
int func(int a) { return a; }
struct Foo { Foo(int (*)(int)) {}; };

class ThisIsGreat {
  Foo one_way = func;     // DMI with copy-initialization syntax
  Foo another_way{func};  // DMI with list-initialization syntax
};
```

Or of course you could use a constructor:

```
class ThisIsSane {
  ThisIsSane()
      : third_way(func)   // constructor-initializer list
  {}

  Foo third_way;
};
```

Language-lawyer note for pedants: In C++11, `ThisIsGreat` is not an aggregate; in C++14 it is.

Comment: I knew that could be done with basic data types,  but for whatever reason my brain seized up and didnt connect the dots to abstract data types as well.  Well..  I am embarrassed to say the least lol,  I need to put the coffee away, fold the laptop, and go to sleep.  Maybe when I wake up later I will have regained some IQ points....  and my dignity. @Kerrek,  again, Thanks!

Comment: As I said, always reduce your problem to the absolute core of the question, and just by doing so you would probably discover the missing link.

Answer (score 0):

1,000 thanks to Kerrek SB.

```
class ThisWorks {
    Foo* working;
    ThisWorks() {
         working = new Foo(func);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is as wrong as it gets. Why did you introduce a pointer? You didn't need a pointer but now you will have to look after it **forever**.

Comment: Oy..   Couldn't figure out how else to do it :/