# Calling private function in lambda from outside the class

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, this

In my current project I am trying to pass a private member function as parameter to another function. In my code, the other function is a member function of a different class, but for keeping it simple, here it is a free function.

```
void outside_function(std::function<void(int)> func) {
  // do something with func
}


class MyClass {
public:
  void run();

private:
  bool my_func(double); // defined in source file
};
```

Now, from inside `run` I want to put `my_func` into `outside_function` as argument. Since the signature of `run` does not fit the requirements for the parameter, I cannot simply pass it. Using the [adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) was my first try, which was when I was reminded that member functions implicitly take the `this` pointer as first argument. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7582576/6608142) answer suggests using a lambda expression, which is what I did.

```
void MyClass::run() {
  outside_function([this](int a) -> void {
    double d = static_cast<double>(a);
    this->my_func(d);
  });
}
```

Why does this work? From my point of understanding, `outside_function` does not have access to `my_func`. Why don't I have to make `my_func` public first? Is it something the compiler does or some C++ rule I don't know?

Additionally, are there any catches to this approach that might break my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`outside_function` never accesses the member (it only knows the type of the `func` parameter and can't possibly care about how it's defined) -- only the lambda function does.

Since you're defining the lambda function inside `MyClass`, you can access all the private names within it.

`outside_function` *calls* the provided function, but if you weren't allowed to call a function that uses any private members, you couldn't do much.

Comment: Ok, I get it. My misunderstanding probably was to think of the lambda as something outside of `MyClass`. Thanks!

Comment: @KorbenDose lambda expression returns a function object defined in the current scope (governed by capture list). Thus it able access whatever is accessible in that scope. it's equivalent of declaring and creating an instance of class that would be initialized with values or\and references from that scope and got `operator()` defined.

Answer (score 6):

`private` access specifier only restrict an object *name* to be visible (it cannot be looked up) outside the class. The object itself is like any other member.

> #### [`[class.access]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access#1)
>
> A member of a class can be
>
> (1.1) private; that is, its name can be used only by members and friends of the class in which it is declared.
>
> (1.2) protected; that is, its name can be used only by members and friends of the class in which it is declared, by classes derived from that class, and by their friends (see [class.protected]).
>
> (1.3) public; that is, its name can be used anywhere without access restriction.