# C++ - Error when trying to push_back a function pointer to a vector located in another CPP File

Tags: c++, pointers, events

### Introduction

I'm new to C++, keep that in mind as i try to explain my problem.

i'm making a game in C++ to help me understand the language better, and while i was making this project i decided that i needed events(like the C# events) to help me with this project, and after some researched i found out that C++ doesn't have a event handler system similar to the C# one, so i tried to do something that worked in the same way as the C# event handler.

In the Main.cpp file i created this:

```
typedef void(*KeyPressedFunction)(sf::Keyboard::Key);
std::vector<KeyPressedFunction> keyPressedEvent;
int main()
{
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;
            case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
                for (KeyPressedFunction func : keyPressedEvent)
                {
                    func(event.key.code);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is that every class that wanted to know when the key was pressed was going to subscribe to the event(`push_back` to the `keyPressedEvent` vector) and when a key gets pressed every system would have that information.

#### The Problem

After i tested the system in the main.cpp file (creating a function and pushing back to the `keyPressedEvent` vector) i noticed that it was working fine, the test functions that i created were being called correctly, so i decided to implement in the rest of the system, which means...in other translation units.

This is what i did:

- Pacman.h File:

  ```
  typedef void(*KeyPressedFunction)(sf::Keyboard::Key);
  extern std::vector<KeyPressedFunction> keyPressedEvent;

  class Pacman
  {
  public:
      Pacman(float x, float y);
      void OnKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key key);
  };
  ```
- Pacman.cpp File:

  ```
  #include "Pacman.h"
  #include <iostream>

  void Pacman::OnKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key key)
  {

  }

  Pacman::Pacman(float x, float y)
  {
      keyPressedEvent.push_back(*OnKeyPressed);
  }
  ```

The line that is causing all the trouble is `keyPressedEvent.push_back(*OnKeyPressed);` this one, even though i'm doing in the same way that i did when testing the "event system" before.

> The error is: "Operand of '*' must be a pointer"

I think this error is somehow related to the vector being located in another translation unit, but i don't have any idea on how to solve.

Comment: Recommended reading: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Pacman::OnKeyPressed` is a *method* (non-static member function), not a regular function. (It has nothing to do with translation units btw). Would that function be static, your code would be OK.

A solution is to use `std::function` instead of function pointers, and `std::bind` to make it out of member function (see also [Using generic std::function objects with member functions in one class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582546/using-generic-stdfunction-objects-with-member-functions-in-one-class)).